# Tengo este error "E/RecyclerView : No adapter attached: skipping layout"

Tags: android-studio

Mi aplicación se cierra cuando accedo a la actividad donde se encuentra mi RecyclerView, me dice que el problema está en mi adaptador pero al ser nuevo en esto la verdad es que no sé cual podría ser la solución.Ya busqué en otras respuestas con el mismo problema, pero sigo sin hacer que funcione.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Categoria> mData;
    private RequestOptions option;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria(Context mContext, List<Categoria> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        //Request option for Glide

        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row_item, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_id.setText(mData.get(position).getId_categoria());
        holder.tv_nombre.setText(mData.get(position).getNombre());

        //Load image from Internet

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImagen_url()).apply(option).into(holder.iv_imagen);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tv_id;
        TextView tv_nombre;
        ImageView iv_imagen;
        LinearLayout view_container;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);


            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            tv_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_id);
            tv_nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_nombre);
            iv_imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_imagen);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega también el código de tu RecyclerView. Posiblemente no estas llamando `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Tengo un error con mi RecyclerView espero me puedan ayudar: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236577/tengo-un-error-con-mi-recyclerview-espero-me-puedan-ayudar-e-recyclerview-no-a)

Comment: ayúdanos a reportar este tipo de casos @RockoDev saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Noto que cuando obtienes la respuesta envías una lista de objetos a el adapter:

```
setuprecyclerview(lista);
```

pero al definir esta lista en el adapter probablemente la petición no obtuvo ningún elemento por lo tanto debes modificar el método  `getItemCount()` de tu Adapter de esta forma:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mData != null)
      return mData.size();
    }else{
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo por otra parte, asegurar la consulta de tu petición esta funcionando correctamente.